# Can reference be compared with pointer?

Tags: c++

I'm studying Copy assignment in C++. If you see the line 5 at the code below, there is "this == &rhs". Is this expression legal? this is a pointer to an obejct and rhs is an reference to object. So it is different.
Or Can reference be compared with pointer?
Thank you.

```
class Mystring{
  //class
};

Mystring& Mystring::operator=(const Mystring &rhs){
  if (this==&rhs)   //<===========this line
    return *this;

  delete [] str;
  str = new char[std::strlen(rhs.str)+1];
  std::strcpy(str, rhs.str);

  return *this;
}
```

Comment: `rhs` is a reference, but `&rhs` is the address of the object it refers to. BTW: I hope that whatever source you're learning from, it's going to address the fact that this code is not exception-safe.

Comment: In `const Mystring &rhs`, `const Mystring &` is the type of `rhs`; in `&rhs`, `&` is an operator. The ampersand, `&`, has three different meanings in C++: as part of a type it indicates a reference type; as a unary operator it is the "address-of" operator; and as a binary operator it is "bitwise and".

Comment: One can only hope that the addressof operator `&` has not been overloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is "this == &rhs". Is this expression legal?

Yes.

> this is a pointer to an obejct and rhs is an reference to object. So it is different.

Yes.

> Or Can reference be compared with pointer?

Potentially yes (if the reference is to a class type with an operator overload for comparing with a pointer), but that's not what the example program does because it doesn't compare pointer with `rhs`. The example programs a pointer with `&rhs` which is also a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> there is "this == &rhs". Is this expression legal?

Yes it is.

Just a sidenote, References are *aliasses* to another variable.

Also a quick optimization of the code below:

```
Mystring& Mystring::operator=(const Mystring &rhs){
   if (this != &rhs)
   {
      delete [] str;
      str = new char[std::strlen(rhs.str)+1];
      std::strcpy(str, rhs.str);
   }
return *this;
}
```

Comment: What have you optimized there in the code? It looks totally equivalent to me. Am I just missing it?

Comment: Instead of checking if the object is the same and returning that as a pointer, i made it where if it isn't the same, it would change it.

So from: "if (this == &rhs)" to "if (this != &rhs)"

Just a form of code standard i apply. But do as you wish.

Comment: @CodyGray He optimized the readability of the code :p As written, there is only one exit point left (i.e. only one `return` statement).